# Parse Query no working in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse sdk to store data.
I am using below code to fetch data from parse.
**I only want those data which are updated after last sync datetime.**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(P_TableName);
// fetch only those data which updated after last updated sync date.
parseQuery.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", date);
List<ParseObject> lstObj = parseQuery.find();
```

**Note: date is Object of Date.**

But still it is providing me all data.
It was working before few days. Now It's not working in android.

Comment: you should try `Cursor` and get data you want.

Comment: In parse sdk how can I use cursor. I have to use method provided by Parse sdk which is "parseQuery.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("updatedAt", date);"

Comment: Any luck ever fixing this?